# Keep a Python script with parameters running, restart if crashed, in a tmux session

Tags: shell-script, scripting, cron, python, tmux

I have a Python script which runs in multiple instances with different parameters, for instance:

```
python3 proc.py -s -v -l proc_one.log
python3 proc.py -c -v -l proc_two.log
```

I usually start these in `tmux` sessions with a script on boot and manually check in on these, to restart if they crashed.

```
tmux new-session -d -s proct 'cd /opt/proct/ && python3 proc.py -s -v -l proc_one.log; bash'
tmux split-window -t proct 'cd /opt/proct/ && python3 proc.py -c -v -l proc_two.log; bash'
```

This is rather tedious and should be automated. I recently came across this solution, which offers kind of what I look for. A cronjob running the following bash script every couple of minutes:

```
if [[ ! $(pgrep -f '^python3 proc.py -s -v -l proc_one.log') ]]; then
    python3 proc.py -s -v -l proc_one.log
fi
```

While this would keep my script running, it would also prevent me form checking in on the process.

---

My question is, how can I have a script check if my process is running, like the one above, but if it is not running, start it in a `tmux` session. I wouldn't mind separate `tmux` sessions for the different instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a service.
Put

```
[Unit]
Description=ProcOfMine
After=network-online.target

[Service]
ExecStart=python proc.py --args ok
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

in

```
/lib/systemd/system/proc.service
```

Also implement error handling so that the script does not crash.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the suggestion. How can I monitor the stdout of the script if it runs as a service?

Comment: I see the output can be viewed with `journalctl`, but it seems to only print the output, once the script exits.

Comment: @boolean.is.null if output is not instant then it may be due to a buffer in your script. You can always redirect to a log file.